# Exceeding App Engine Max Number of Instances

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to setup an App Engine with a very high number of instances. When I try to set the number on either basic or manual scaling and deploy I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: version.manual_scaling.instances (50.0) must be in the range [1.0, 25.0].
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: version.manual_scaling.instances (50.0) must be in the range [1.0,
      25.0].
    field: version.manual_scaling.instances
```

I thought that I could set very high numbers of instances in either Basic or Manual Scaling so I am not sure why I am getting that the range is only 1 to 25? Is there some additional setting I need to configure on GCloud to enable a higher instance count?

Comment: This is not a direct answer - if you want a 'high' number of instances, why not use 'automatic' scaling so that GAE provides as many instances as needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a high number of App Engine instances will depend on your Google Cloud project resources instance [quota](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas). Based on the error, you are only applicable for  1 to 25 instances running in your App Engine. If you want to increase your quota limit, you can file a quota request by following the steps in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota).

@NoCommandLine's comment is correct, if you want that App Engine handle your instance, use [automatic scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/how-instances-are-managed#apps_with_automatic_scaling). **Note**, automatic scaling will also depend on your Project instance quota, but it will minimize your cost rather than basic scaling, or manual scaling.